# How to do a non-waiting write on a named pipe (c#)?

Tags: c#, named-pipes, nonblocking, client-server

I'm using .net 3.5 named pipes and my server side is :

```
serverPipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("myPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
```

When I write some data with, say, BinaryWriter, the write() call itself doesn't return until the client side has called a read() on its NamedPipeClientStream.

The BinaryWriter is :

```
writer = new BinaryWriter(serverPipeStream);
```

I'm aware that NamedPipeServerStream offers a BeginRead/BeginWrite but from what I gather, named pipes are supposed to allow streamwriters to perform on top of them (as seen in many Microsoft-given examples).

So how can I make my write() to the named pipe non-waiting ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is BinaryWriter doesn't have a `BeginWrite` function so, as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/11f6aa76-1383-4cab-8693-29dcb25bbf2e), you could write to a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) and then use the its buffer to pass to the `BeginWrite` function of the pipe.

Hope that helps.